# DNS query dynamic processing possibilities

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm building a DNS manager. 
A database has information about clients and destinations, and some criteria upon which some destinations or sources must be blocked or bypassed.

I'm somewhat confused regarding the possibilities of the name server...

I know what I need can be achieved through the use of views and rpz in bind (my current approach), but I'm wondering if there is a more "on the fly" way to make a check before returning an answer, e.g. looking at request source and destination, querying the db and **then** deciding what to return (suppose status can change from time to time), opposed to having the answer "waiting" in a zone file.

So, making this kind of checks would imply programming a nameserver from scratch?

Would that violate some kind of standard?

Is there any "better fit" than bind for this?

It appears that rpz is the "legal" way of doing this but from all the documents I've read I can't figure out *why* (I mean, is it a standard? is it a condition of existence for a NS? can I break the internet or will internet police come get me?)

I have the feel I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough to me.

RPZ is not a standard (in the sense of an IETF standard) it is just a new feature that some nameservers now provide.

Some others nameservers than bind provide you a dynamic interface where you can plug a program that will decide what to reply.

See this example: https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/backend-lua/

Many nameservers allow to be pluged to a database. It is less dynamic than a program but still allows more "live" configuration. It exists for bind, see http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/

You can develop a nameserver from scratch if you would like, but be advised that this is not a simple task. A nameserver is far more than something doing a mapping between a requested name and a replied IP address. You have many fine points to understand and implement properly, and the documentation (standards) is splitted in many files of various qualities that interact between each other (it is in fact a subject under discussion right now in the IETF working group and since the latest IETF meeting; see for example this newest attemps at some clear and global documentation on the DNS protocol: https://powerdns.org/hello-dns/)

If you do wrong, there is no Internet Police to shut you down but you will surely get annoyed customers (if they host their zone with you and it does not work correctly from everywhere), purists taking your case as an example, and doing name and shame here: https://github.com/dns-violations/dns-violations

Comment: Thanks. I finally used powerdns recursor with Lua, which is exactly what I needed.
Be aware that your answer has been helpful in clearing the confusion. It is true that the question is not clear enough. It resembles the confusion that originated it.